# How to downsample timeseries in QuestDb?

Tags: time-series, questdb

I have a table with metrics per box in QuestDb with columns

- Timestamp (designated timestamp)
- Machine (Symbol)
- CPU (double)

and I want to downsample the results to 2 min interval taking average per machine so that output is same columns but with 1 data point per every 2 mins per every machine. I have a feeling that there should be a special SQL extension syntax for that but cannot make it work so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sample by](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/sample-by/#syntax) for that

```
SELECT Timestamp, Machine, AVG(CPU)
FROM tablename
SAMPLE BY 2m
```

This will automatically group by Machine and 2 mins timestamp intervals